# Reference filename via xcom in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to understand how to pass values via `airflow` `xcom` functionality. The specific usecase I am trying to build is to write a file, then move it, then run another command. The idea is that I pass the file name from one operator to the next.

Here is what I have:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import datetime as dt

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='xcom_test_dag',
  start_date=dt.datetime.now(),
  schedule_interval='@once'
)

def push_function(**context):
    file_name = 'test_file_{date}'.format(date=dt.datetime.now())
    return context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='filename', value=file_name)

def pull_function(**context):
    dir(context['task_instance'].xcom_pull())

push_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_task', 
    python_callable=push_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

pull_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pull_task', 
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

push_task >> pull_task
```

If I want to reference the file name in the pull_task so I could perform read the file - how should I call that? Trying to access `context['task_instance']` does not contain a value. Further - is it best practices to try and reference a file name like this from task to task/operator to operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pulling data from XCOM, you want to provide the task ID of the task where you push the data. In your example, the task_id of your push task is `push_task`, so you'd want to do something like:

```
value = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task')
```

However, from the airflow documentation, note that:

> By default, xcom_pull() filters for the keys that are automatically given to XComs when they are pushed by being returned from execute functions (as opposed to XComs that are pushed manually).

If you're pushing data to XCOM manually with specific keys, you may need to include that key when calling `xcom_pull`. In your example, you push a key called `filename` in your push task, so you'd likely need to do something like this in your pull task:

```
value = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task', key='filename')
```

This information is outlined in further detail in the Airflow documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#concepts-xcom

As for your question regarding "best practices" - for communicating between Airflow Tasks/Operators, XCOM is the best way to go. However, if you're wanting to read a file from disk across multiple operators, you would need to ensure that all your workers have access to where the file is stored. If that isn't possible, an alternative could be to have the push task store that file remotely (e.g. in [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)) and push the S3 URL to XCOM. The pull task could then read the S3 URL from XCOM, and download the file from S3.